# Index sort. Something really weird is going on

Tags: java

```
       public int[] indexSort(){
    int[] sortedarr = new int[max];

    for(int i=0;i<max;i++){
        int key=0;
        int duplicates = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<max;j++){
            if(arr[i]>arr[j]) key++;
            else if(arr[i]==arr[j]) duplicates++;

        }
        while(duplicates>0&&key<max){


            sortedarr[key] = arr[i];
            key++;
            duplicates--;
        }
    }
    return sortedarr; }
```

How comes does the while loop work? Even when there are no duplicates(duplicates=0), the while loop is still executed.

My mind is puzzled. Also is index sort supposed to run by O(n^3)?

Answer (score 1):

There's always a "duplicate" : when `i == j`.

You should probably start the inner loop at `i+1` :

```
for(int i=0;i<max;i++){
    int key=0;
    int duplicates = 0;
    for(int j=i+1;j<max;j++){
```

Comment: Damn didn't see that. Your implementation didn't fixed the compile error, but it gave wrong output. I just had to compensate for duplicates always being on in my code by putting i!=j condition. Thanks for the help, is index sort supposed to be n^3 though? I can't find anything about that sort on google.